# LazyInitializationException in spite of Spring transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

The method below results in the `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` being thrown and I'd appreciate help in understanding why. I'm using JPA 2/Hibernate & Spring.

JPA 2/Hibernate are using the default `transaction` persistence context, therefore, shouldn't the method below allow for lazy loading?

```
@Service
public class GalleryService {
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Response getGallery(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        Gallery g = daoWrapper.findById(Gallery.class, id);
        ...
        GalleryDto gDto = new GalleryDto();
        ...
        // getImages() returns a collection of 'image' objects.
        gDto.setImages(g.getImages());
        return Response.ok(gDto).build();
    }
}
```

**Note**: `daoWrapper` is a convenience class that wraps entity manager methods.

```
@Repository
public class daoWrapper implements BaseDao {

   @PersistenceContext(unitName="persistStore") 
   private EntityManager em;

   @Override
   public <T,U> T findById(Class<T> entity, U id) {
        return this.em.find(entity, id);
   }
   ...
}
```

The application context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.services"/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
...
</beans>
```

Answer (score 4):

There's an awful lot more information we'd need to diagnose that, but my inclination seeing your signature is that it's in a controller class that isn't being proxied.  The @Transactional is only going to work on classes that are being proxied by the bean factory, in many common ways to set up the context, this does not include controller classes.

Comment: The spring configuration that defines the bean you're annotating, what kind of proxying you're using, what daoWrapper actually does.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you're using JDK proxies?  GalleryService needs to implement an interface that has that method on it in order for spring to be able to generate a proxy and apply the transactional advice.

Comment: Is there a way to resolve this problem without creating & implementing an interface with the desired method? I have other similarly constructed classes that lazily load without any problems. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sure, there are lots, trying that and seeing if it fixes it would tell us that proxying is indeed the problem though.  It also matters with JDK proxies where you are calling the method from.  transactional won't work if you call another method on the same class.

Answer (score 0):

What @Affe was asking for is your spring configuration? If you are getting a LazyInitializationException then there is no transaction in place. As @Affe mentioned, Transaction will be started only if the proxies are created and this could be because of some issue in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I caught the same issue when called

```
session.clear();
```

somewhere in between

```
entity = session.get(...);
```

and

```
entity.getLazyCollection();
```

So simply check your code to not use this method.